# PHP GeoIP causing 500 error

Tags: php

I'm very confused with this issue but I was attempting to detect a users IP address and perform a redirect based on the users country code. In order to do this I used the following piece of code:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
require_once("geoip.inc");
$gi = geoip_open("GeoIP.dat", GEOIP_STANDARD);
$country_code = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
geoip_close($gi);
if ($country != "GB" && strpos($url, '/?') === false) {
   if ($country_code == "IE") {
      header("Location: https://www.mymainsite.com");
      die();
   } else {
      header("Location: http://www.othersite.com");
      die();
   }
}
```

However each time I run the code I get a 500 Server error. I've managed to narrow down the line of code that is causing it:

```
require_once("geoip.inc");
```

If I remove this line the problem is gone but obviously I need the file as it's crucial to the geolocation.

Would anyone have any idea as to why it could be throwing a 500 error?

Many thanks

Comment: Check dem log files... if you don't know where they are at, you can do `php -i | grep error_log` from command line.

Comment: Is the path to geoip.inc correct? Permissions correct?

Comment: Hi yes, the path is correct, it is in same directory and the permissions are set to 664

Comment: Mike when I run that command I get this message: error_log => no value => no value
PHP Warning:  Unknown: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Are you in a dev or prod environment? If dev, you could add these to the start of the script: `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I actually found the problem out. Your idea of checking logs worked I just had to go digging for them a bit!. I'll post what I did now and reason for inital problem.

Comment: Have you consider other geolocation library such as IP2Location LITE to avoid calling the library in problem?

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this for anyone who is looking to implement geoip functionality on their site but runs into a similar issue.

The reason for the above error is due to the fact that the file `geoip.inc` is loaded in an environment where the `geoip extension` is enabled.

Both `geoip.inc` and the `geoip extension` declare a method with the same name resulting in a conflict. Ideally there should be a check before calling the function to see if it exists which can be done like so:

```
if (!function_exists('geoip_country_name_by_name')) {
    function geoip_country_name_by_name($gi, $name) {
        $country_id = geoip_country_id_by_name($gi, $name);
        if ($country_id !== false) {
            return $gi->GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAMES[$country_id];
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Just simply wrap the offending function in the `ìf` statement:

`if(!function_exists('name_of_function')){.....}`

and the problem is rectified.

I also should mention that @MikePurcells suggestion of looking through the server logs helped big time. My development server is an Apache Server running linux Redhat. The logs are located in /var/log/httpd/error_log. That's where I checked and discovered this error:

```
[Wed Oct 28 15:49:33 2015] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xx] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare geoip_country_code_by_name()
```

Hope that helps anyone.

Comment: You'll come to realize that log files are indispensable tool in our industry, not just for httpd services like Apache or NGinx, but pretty much any service. When in doubt check the logs.

Comment: Yes, again Mike appreciate you pointing me in right direction. I was really stumped